# Why it takes a MINUTE to get a respond from server?

Tags: php, sockets

I am new to PHP socket programming and I found an example to experiment with, but when I talk to my server, it takes a minute to get the respond before server socket closes.

I have the following code:
SERVER.php

```
<?php 

$host = "127.0.0.1"; 
$port = 1234; 

// don't timeout! 
set_time_limit(0); 

// create socket 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n"); 

// bind socket to port 
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n"); 

// start listening for connections 
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n"); 

// accept incoming connections 
// spawn another socket to handle communication 
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n"); 

// read client input 
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n"); 

// clean up input string 
$input = trim($input); 

// reverse client input and send back 
$output = strrev($input) . "\n"; 
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n"); 

// close sockets 
socket_close($spawn); 
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

How can get it to respond right away? Thanks

When I run the client code in terminal, I get the response right away. But when I add a text box to run it from the browser, it takes exactly 1 minute to get the response to show on my browser.

If you need to look at my CLIENT.php
Here it is...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
Enter some text:<br>
<input type="Text" name="message" size="15"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// form submitted

// where is the socket server?
$host="127.0.0.1";
$port = 1234;

// open a client connection
$fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

if (!$fp)
{
$result = "Error: could not open socket connection";
}
else
{
// get the welcome message
fgets ($fp, 1024);
// write the user string to the socket
fputs ($fp, $_POST['message']);
// get the result
$result .= fgets ($fp, 1024);
// close the connection
fputs ($fp, "exit");
fclose ($fp);

// trim the result and remove the starting ?
$result = trim($result);

// now print it to the browser
}
?>
Server said: <b><? echo $result; ?></b>
<?
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting a error??

Comment: Read question carefully. OP is asking why response takes 1 minute to come.

Comment: Why it take a minute me understand you?

Comment: Do I need to make something clear for you? Aguyfromhere

Comment: From you question. ..I understand now why...hope it was not sarcasm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your server first reads first and *then* writes back a response. Your client does the *same thing* though, expecting a "welcome message" which I can't see your server ever sending. So they both sit there waiting for a data from each other. Perhaps commenting out the line where you get the (seemingly non-existent) welcome message should relieve that deadlock.

```
// get the welcome message
// fgets ($fp, 1024);
```

That, or be sure to actually send a welcome message from the server as soon as the client connects.

You say that it works right away in the terminal. I can only guess that somehow a newline (as a result of the ENTER key) is being sent which fulfills the `fgets` call in the client.

Also it seems like you should be able to use the `socket_*` functions you used in the server in the client as well. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166182/php-socket-java-message-exchange) for more information.